# How to display the discount for each item in the invoice?

Tags: php, woocommerce

Hi there so I'm pretty new to php in woocommerce. I need to try and get the discount to show for each product in the invoice and was wondering if anyone could help with this.

[image: discount]

[image: invoice]

So far I have been able to figure out this part and my only problem is getting the discount to show up.

```
<?php 
        $items = $this->get_order_items();
        $discount = $order->get_discount_to_display();
        if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ) : ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo apply_filters( 'wpo_wcpdf_item_row_class', $item_id, $this->type, $this->order, $item_id ); ?>">
<td class="quantity"><?php echo $item['quantity']; ?></td>
        <td class="discount"><?php echo $discount ?></td>
        <td class="price"><?php echo $item['order_price']; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

i m using your code in my invoice template it shows me 0$ discount for every order??

Comment: No I don't get $0, I get nothing to show in my column when I try and echo it.

Comment: any solutin you found for discout to show on pdf invoice in woocomerce??

Comment: I wasn't able to find anything that could specifically help me out.